# how to prevent sessions id from being seen in debuggers?

Tags: php, security, session

So it seems like Opera Dragonfly is able to cache cookies as well as session info. In particular the PHPSSID my question is. Would there be a way to hide PHPSSID from being shown by any time of debugger/developer tool?

I don't mind cookies since they are secured. As the data in them is hashed with double salt as well as few other things so forging them is no a problem for me.

But I want to assure PHP sessions are not seen. How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: I don't believe that you can. Your best bet is to make sure that a cached session can't be used to modify anything on the site. (ex: Allow the user to remain logged in, but require a password to perform any action that changes settings.)

Comment: I am planning to regenerate sessions after any changes with user data so ex: password change, e-mail change ect ect ect would kill old session and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

In short the answer is: **You can't, that is not session id's work.**

The point of a session id is that is a very random number,  often called a [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).  This value is intended to be very difficult to guess,  it is then used to reference state about that session on the server side.   This could be in a database or by default PHP uses the file `/tmp/THE_SESSION_ID`.     The data stored in `$_SESSION` is stored in this file and the user cannot obtain this data.

In PHP to keep attackers from stealing a user's session id you should set `session.cookie_secure=On` in your [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure).  This forces the session to be over HTTPS.

If you are using HTTPS,  then the session id will be obscured from attackers on that network. By using HTTPS session id's cannot be hijacked with tools like Wireshark or [Firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep).   Not using HTTPS is a violation of [OWASP A9: Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).   However a user can still see his own session id by looking at his cookies `javascript:document.cookie`  or by using TamperData.

Comment: but dont you need an valid certificate first to use HTTPS? and that sadly costs money which I dont want to pay as I am not passing any important data

Comment: If you aren't passing any important data, then why do you care so much about the session id.  Just us regular HTTP for the session id.  And as was mentioned, the session key just links the user to the session and that's it. As Rich said in other answer, session id is just a cookie on the users machine, there's nothing you can do to stop the user from seeing it, or setting their own value for it.

Comment: @Kibbee and PT Desu Authentication credentials (the session id) is important information.   In any secuirty system you have to be clear who the attacker is.  The user seeing their own session id is clearly not an attack,  but anyone else obtaining this session id is a very serious owasp violation that could give an attacker admin access to your application.